# How can I link my site to PayPal API and display PayPal button using MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, paypal

How can I display Paypal payment option from my website, so clicking on the PayPal button shall open up PayPal login information screen and from there user can process that payment.

My application is on MVC3. Could anyone explain me how can i make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can signup with Paypal as a merchant user and they will allow you to embed a button on your site. And then Paypal will take care of the rest.

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_merchant-get-started-outside